# Как получить координаты обектов в svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, svg

Как задать или получить координаты получить координаты каждго елемента в теге svg ?

Например получить координаты каждго елемента в теге  Вот пример разметки :

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 800 800" enable-background="new 0 0 800 800" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="80" y="80" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="160" y="160" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="240" y="240" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="400" y="240" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="400" y="320" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="480" y="320" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="560" y="320" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="640" y="320" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="560" y="480" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="560" y="560" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="400" y="480" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="400" y="560" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="640" y="640" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="560" y="640" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
    <rect x="400" y="640" fill="#ED2224" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="80" height="80"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Например получить координаты каждго елемента в теге <svg>

Comment: Та разметка, что вы привели, не валидна. В этом легко убедится с помощью https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Я привел в пример только часть разметки (чтоб было понятно , что я хочу. По этому выбивает , что она не валидна. А вообще то нужны координаты каждого отдельного rect

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что правильный код может не работать на невалидной разметку? И как по-вашему тогда убедится в правильности решения?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev извините , исправил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У SVG элементов есть аттрибуты `x` и `y`. Именно они определяют позицию элемента. Подробное описание свойств доступно, например, в MDN:

x: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x
y: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/y

Теперь о том как с этим работать. Если вы используете jQuery, то можно, например, так:

```
$('rect').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        x = parseInt($el.attr('x'), 10) || 0,
        y = parseInt($el.attr('y'), 10) || 0;

   // Можно вывести значения в консоль.
   console.log(x + ': ' + y);

   // А можно сместить каждый из элементов.
   $el.attr('x', x + 5);
   $el.attr('y', y + 5);
});
```